# Add class to another class property public List<Class> ListOfThatClass { get; set; }

Tags: c#, class, nullreferenceexception, generic-list

*First class*

```
 class Tasks
{
    public List<Ck> listCk { get; set; }
}
```

*Second Class*

```
class Ck
{
    public string CkName { get; set; }
    public string CkConentent { get; set; }
}
```

*Now I wanna add Ck to Tasks.listCk*

```
Tasks t = new Tasks();
Ck ck = new Ck();
ck.CkName = "s1";
ck.CkConentent = "s2";

t.listCk.Add(ck); //Here I get NullReferenceException
```

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>   MojDevnik.Tasks.listaCk.get returned null.

Comment: `t.listCk` is null. You need to do `t.listCk = new List<Co>();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise your list, you can do that in either the constructor or before you assign some value to it. Below is an example of how to do it in a constructor.

```
class Tasks
{
    public List<Ck> listCk { get; set; }

    public Task() {
        listCk = new List<Ck>();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate you list first

change this

```
 class Tasks
{
    public List<Ck> listCk { get; set; }
}
```

to

```
 class Tasks
{
    public List<Ck> listCk { get; set; } = new List<Ck>();
}
```

or

```
Tasks t = new Tasks();
                Ck ck = new Ck();
                ck.CkName = "s1";
                ck.CkConentent = "s2";

                t.listCk.Add(ck); *Here i get NullReferenceException*
```

to

```
Tasks t = new Tasks();
                Ck ck = new Ck(){listCk  = new List<Ck>()};
                ck.CkName = "s1";
                ck.CkConentent = "s2";

                t.listCk.Add(ck); *Here i get NullReferenceException*
```

or

add a constructor

```
   class Tasks
{
    public List<Ck> listCk { get; set; }

    public Task() {
        listCk = new List<Ck>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, now it works. When i do Tasks t =  new Tasks(); doesn't all properties get  instantiated?

Comment: No, you have to explicitly create their instance because the list is not created yet and you are trying to add elements to an null list :)